# Please help with this volume of solid of rotation question

Tags: integration, volume, rotations

Find the volumes of the solids generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of the equations about the y-axis.

$$y = \sqrt(x), y=0, x=6$$

The reason this is confusing to me is because it's asking me to take an area that is bounded by the x axis, a function, and another line, and rotate it about the y axis. If the area were bounded by the y axis instead of the x axis, this would make much more sense to me.

If I want to revolve the function about the y axis, I should make it in terms of y:
$$y=\sqrt{x} , x=y^2$$
So to integrate with respect to y using $0$ to $6$ on the x-axis as my bounds, I have to convert my bounds to be on the y-axis, and they become $0$ and $\sqrt{6}$.
Then, I can try to integrate. The problem is that if I just integrate the function normally with respect to y, I'm finding the area bound by the function and the y axis:
$$\int_0^\sqrt{6}y^2dy$$

So, with respect to y, I tried treating it like the area between the function $x=6$ and $y^2$:
$$\int_0^\sqrt{6} 6-y^2 dx$$

Then, using the disk method formula, the volume would be:
$$π\int_0^\sqrt{6} (6-y^2)^2dy$$
Evaluate that and you get $\pi(\frac{96\sqrt{6}}{5})$, which my online homework's autochecker said was wrong. Could someone tell me my error in reasoning here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the region you are trying to rotate does not touch the axis of rotation, the "disks" you get have circular holes in the middle.

Some people use the term *washer method* for this technique. where the "washer" is a disk with a hole in the middle, like the washers that one might use when assembling some mechanical object with nuts and bolts.

There are some explanations [here](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sparling/23012/23012volints1/23012volints3/node2.html) and [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx). Note that the second link calls this the method of disks or the method of rings, but the formula for rotation around the $y$ axis is the same no matter what you call the method:

$$ \int_a^b A(y)\,dy
 = \int_a^b \pi ((\text{outer radius})^2 - (\text{inner radius})^2)\, dy. $$

This is because $A(y)$ is the area of a disk-with-a-hole (also called washer or ring or annulus) with an outer radius and an inner radius.
If it were a disk with the given outer radius and no hole, its area would be
$\pi (\text{outer radius})^2,$ but the hole removes
$\pi (\text{inner radius})^2$ from the area.

What you did was 
$$\int_a^b \pi ((\text{outer radius}) - (\text{inner radius}))^2\, dy $$

which is effectively the area of a smaller disk without a hole.
You get a smaller result that way.